# How to distinguish odd and even for big numbers more efficiently?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, numeric, numerical-methods

Please let me know by comments if there are already some similar questions.

When we usually try to distinguish odd and even numbers we can try the following code,
in C++.

```
    int main() {
        int n=10;
        
        for(n; n>0; n--){
            
            if(n%2==0) std::cout<< "even" << '\n';
            if(n%2==1) std::cout<< "odd" << '\n';      
        }   
    }
```

I'm sure more than 99% of undergraduates, even professionals, would use condition as "if (n%2==0)...else" to distinguish between odd and even.

However, **when the range of number gets big enough**, it seems to me that "if (n%2==0)...else" method could be quite inefficient. Let me reason them why.

```
 int main() {
        int n=100000;
        
        for(n; n>0; n--){
            
            if(n%2==0) std::cout<< "even" << '\n';
            if(n%2==1) std::cout<< "odd" << '\n';      
        }   
    }
```

when the integer "n" was small then dividing each of positive integer smaller than it wasn't a big deal.

However, when it becomes big, wouldn't there be some more efficient way than just dividing them?

We, humans, usually don't calculate modulo 2 to know whether "10^1000 + 1" is odd or even.
It goes same for ""10^1000 + 2", "10^1000 + 3", and so on. We can just know the answer by looking at the last digit of integer.

I'm not an expert in CS, so even though I'm not sure about this information, I heard machines are much more friendly to binary numbers than humans do. If so, wouldn't computers can distinguish between odd and even numbers more faster just by looking at the last digit of their inputs, whether they are 0 or 1?

If there is some direct answer to this, I'm sure many of intermediate level of numerical algorithms could benefit from the answer. Looking forward for someone's help.

Thanks.

Comment: Build with optimizations enabled, and look at the generated assembly code. It could be that the compiler is smarter than you think, and recognizes this case.

Comment: You can check if `int n` is even or odd by checking if `n & 1` is `0` or `1` (respectively). I believe any decent compiler knows this and will produce the same code whether you write `(n % 2) == 1` or `(n & 1) == 1`.

Comment: On another note, have you really *measured* that a division like `5 / 2` is really slower than `5000000000 % 2`? What's your basis for that assumption? And will it really be possible to measure any possible difference in a loop where you write output (which is *really* slow)?

Comment: I do not understand, `n%2==0` is super very efficient. `Let me reason them why.` Where is the reasoning? Surely a program that writes 50000 times the string `even\nodd\n` to the output will be slow, that's a lot of writing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: No basis for the assumption. Is the performance time for 50000000%2 and 5%2 really the same?

Comment: @user281 obviously, as long as both fit into a single register. Execution time doesn't depend on the size of the value (except a few rare cases in very complex instructions)

Comment: @phuciv: lol, I didn't know that. I'm so newbie on this kind of question. Thanks for everyone with their comments.

Comment: @phuclv: That is generally true today, with high-performance CPU's. Silicon is very cheap. But in some cheaper microcontrollers, operations might be done in chunks smaller than a register. E.g. 32 bits registers with 8 bit adders - here a dedicated 16 bits add may take only 2 cycles instead of the usual 4 for a full 32 bits add.

Comment: If `n%2==0` is so slow then how is `n%2==0` and `n%2==1` going to be faster? You are now doing 2 of those "slow divisions" instead of using `else`. And surprise surprise the compiler actually does now that `%2` only needs to look at the last digit. And since `int` uses binary that last digit is just the last bit and is `0` or `1`. The code should turn into `std::cout << ((n & 1) ? "odd" : "even") << '\n';`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Thanks, others have pointed out the same thing as yours. I'm a newbie to C/C++ so hope for your advice at another question.

Comment: It is not sure that the speed of a division by 2 depends on the value of the divisor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the performance time for 50000000%2 and 5%2 really the same?

This is making the assumption that the compiler "looks at the number" and "knows" how big its value is. Thats not the case for divisions. The compiler sees an `int` and performs some operations on that `int`. Different values are merely different bits set in that `int` which always has the same number of  bytes that need to be considered when carrying out a division.

On the other hand, `%2` is such a common operation that the compiler indeed "knows where to look": The last bit.

Consider this two functions:

```
bool is_odd1(int n) { return (n%2);} 
bool is_odd2(int n) { return (n&1);}
```

Both return `true` when `n` is odd.

`is_odd1` uses `%` which is defined as remainder after division. Though, just because it is defined like that does not imply that it must be implemented like this. The compiler will emit code that produces the result in accordance with the definition, and that code can be expected to be very efficient.

`is_odd2` only considers the lowest bit of `n` to check if it is set or not.

With optimizations turned on gcc produces exact same output for both:

```
is_odd1(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        and     eax, 1
        ret
is_odd2(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        and     eax, 1
        ret
```

Both function do nothing but check if the lowest bit of `n` is set.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6EsoroT64).

Conclusion: Do not worry about such micro optimizations. If possible they are implemented in the compiler. Rather write code for clarity and readability.

However, do not introduce inefficiencies on the large scale. For example if you had written your code like this, there would be no need to rely on compiler optimizations:

```
    for(; n>0; n-=2){
        std::cout<< "even" << '\n';
        std::cout<< "odd" << '\n';      
    }
```

Though, this is anyhow not a good example, because printing something to the console is magnitudes more expensive than checking if a single bit is set or not.

Comment: Additional question. Does your compiler argument goes the same for python and JavaScript(NodeJS) and most of other languages?

Comment: @user281 python is interpreted and JavaScript I don't know

Comment: Thanks!! I will look for it myself.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at a number written in decimal, you can know quickly whether it is odd or even:

- if it ends with 0, 2, 4, 6, or 8, then it is even;
- if it ends with 1, 3, 5, 7, or 9, then it is odd.

Numbers on a computer are stored in binary. Binary is almost the same as decimal, except it uses base-2 instead of base-10, and thus uses only bits 0 or 1 instead of digits 0 to 9.

To check whether a number written in binary is odd or even, look at its last bit:

- if it ends with 0, then it is even;
- if it ends with 1, then it is odd.

When you write `n % 2 == 0` is C++, your compiler optimises the code and doesn't perform a division at all. Instead, it simply looks at the last bit of `n` and checks whether it is a 0 or a 1.

Comment: I've chosen the other answer because he spent more time to my question than what it deserves. However, your answer also solves my curiosity perfectly. Thank you for your time spent.

Answer (score 1):

Never test parity by testing the remainder (remainder, as well as division, is a very slow operation). It is enough to test the least significant bit by using bit masking (`n & 1 == 0`).

[By the way, smart optimizers will automatically substitute `a % 2` test by masking. Another option is to use shifts: `a == (a >> 1) << 1` detects an even number.]

If your number is a BigNum, it suffices to check the parity of the low order word in the representation.

Comment: Actually your answer was already on comment. I didn't concentrate on the comment much after knowing that the compiler does the job for it. However, I would like to ask whether the bit masking method you've mentioned works for other programming languages as Python and JavaScript? I was curious since I cannot check for each compiler for each language every time.

Comment: @user281: bit masking will "work" in any language that supports bit masking ! Anyway, don't expect the automatic optimization of `% 2` to be performed. Python is not compiled.

Comment: Thanks!! Yup, I've found that Python is terribly slow so I would not consider it as a main tool for numeric algorithm.

Comment: Python is slow (not terribly) when only scalar operations are performed. But in many cases implicit loop constructs can be used, giving a good speedup. And last but not least, Python wraps excellent numerical libraries written in C or C++, with unbeatable performance.

Comment: In my algorithm, Python took 40 times more than C++ and NodeJS codes. The difference of running time got much bigger as the argument got bigger. However, I note your advice that Python can be useful in some cases that I only hear good things with NumPy.

Comment: Maybe I shall try your bit masking method with Python code.

Comment: @user281: you need a global view on the problem you are handling and a good understanding of where time is wasted. If mostly linear algebra or standard numerical analysis, do rely on a library.